# Change Default Printer paper size with PHP powershell script

Tags: php, powershell, printing

I am trying to change Default printer paper size from PHP

**Index.php**

```
<?php
$printer = Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command "(Get-WmiObject win32_printer | Where-Object Default -eq $True).Name"');

$printer = substr($printer, 0, -1);
$printer = '"' . $printer . '"';
$cmd = ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command ../A5.ps1 ' .$printer);
echo shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

**A5.ps1**

```
$printer=$args[0]
Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $printer -PaperSize A5
```

**Error**

```
Set-PrintConfiguration : The specified printer was not found. At C:\Users\t4taa\Desktop\phpdesktop\A5.ps1:2 char:1 + Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $printer -PaperSize A5 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (MSFT_PrinterConfiguration:ROOT/StandardCi...erConfiguration) [Set-PrintCo nfiguration], CimException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070709,Set-PrintConfiguration
```

When I run script file from PowerShell works fine but from PHP it's refuse to take printer name or miss double quotes, how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Instead of launching Powershell twice, just change the script so that it looks up the default printer _and_ changes the paper size. There is no need to parse printer name in PHP at all.

Comment: What is the content of `A5.ps1` ? I used a modified version of the above with my own commands in a file of that name to test and it worked OK - but rather than using `'"'.$printer.'"'` etc I used `sprintf` to help form the cmd strings

Comment: Thank you for your response could you please share complete code with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change the `A5.ps1` into

```
$printer = (Get-WmiObject win32_Printer | Where-Object { $_.Default -eq $true }).Name
Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $printer -PaperSize A5
```

to have powershell figure out the default printer name AND set the papersize.

That way you can do in the `index.php`:

```
<?php
$cmd = ('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File ../A5.ps1');
echo shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

<sup>Use `-File` instead of `-Command`</sup>